# Build a extjs app that I only have the sourcecode

Tags: extjs

I have the sourcecode of an extjs app, complete with ext-all-debug.js, but not the .sencha directory, which my fired coworker claims does not exist.
Now I am trying to use sencha cmd to build a distributable version of the app - minified, if possible even obfuscated code, ext-all.js without debug and without all the unused parts, and everything neatly packed in a single js file.

How would one do so?

I already copied a .sencha directory from another app, but of course it does not work out, Sencha Cmd throwing errors everywhere. Before I spend hours resolving all these errors: Is this the way to go? And is it the only way to go? Or the fastest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience if you are using Sencha cmd, you are better off using a new workspace or app. Then port your code base in.  It may be a bit cumbersome, but at least you will be able to get it piecemeal. Otherwise, it isn't well enough documented to port it over easily.